# when a presheaf is a sheaf

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I've seen a very natural definition when a presheaf $F:C^{op}\rightarrow Set$ is actually a *sheaf*. This definition used the functors $hom(-,-)$ and $F$ and notions of *injective* and *surjective* maps between two particular sets of natural transformations and probably also the notion of *subfunctor*.It claimed that the induced map,whose definition I do not remember now,and which I would like to understand, is always injective and it is surjective iff $F$ is a sheaf.I'm unable to Google this definition again. Any help or hint how such a definition may go?

Comment: Do you mean the [categorical definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29#Sheaves) using an equalizer diagram?

Comment: No. This definition didn't use any form of equalizer as is usual.It only used inclusion from one set of n.t. into another in which appeared F, hom and some object U from C.The point was that this induced inclusion was surjective iff F is a sheaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F$ is a sheaf if and only if the map
$$\mathrm{Hom} (h_X, F) \to \mathrm{Hom} (\mathfrak{U}, F)$$
is a bijection for all covering sieves $\mathfrak{U} \hookrightarrow h_X$. This is just a sophisticated way of rephrasing the standard definition using equalisers and products.

Comment: Is this bijection trivially always injective or always surjective? Which one holds, and why?

Comment: Neither holds in general.